# std::map - how to change key sorting?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, dictionary, stl

I have a problem with `std::map`.
I'm using it to map some list of pairs under a specific index:

```
map<string, list<pair<string, int> > > List;
```

It's used in Dijkstra algorithm.
The main problem is that map sorts `string` keys in alphabetical order, like this:

```
AAA, AA0, AA1, AAB, AC1 = AA0->AA1->AAA->AAB->AC1
```

But I would like to sort it in a different way:

```
AAA, AA0, AA1, AAB, AC1 = AAA->AAB->AA0->AA1->AC1
```

Is there any solution to this? I read about making my own comparing class, but I have no idea how to do this. Or maybe there's some other way to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to provide your own comparison functor, which must be passed as 3rd template parameter when instantiating the map. For example:

```
struct Comp
{
  bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const
  {
    // implement your comparison logic here
  }
};
```

Instances of this class is callable (hence "functor") with two string parameters, and should return true or false based in a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) logic.

Then instantiate the map using the functor type:

```
std::map<string, list<pair<string, int>>, Comp> List;
```

Now the map will use your comparison logic internally to define the ordering of its elements.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but how can I compare strings for differences? I mean, how can I find a digit inside string?

Comment: @user2342783 That's a _completely_ different question. You should ask that in a new question

Comment: @user2342783 that's a different question. But you can iterate over the elements of a string (each of which is a `char`), and do things like call [std::isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) on them.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, you need to implement a custom comparer...

```
struct custom_comparer
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& left, const std::string& right) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(
            left.cbegin(), left.cend(), 
            right.cbegin(), right.cend(),
            [](char l, char r) -> bool
            {
                 bool ldigit = isdigit(l) != 0,
                      rdigit = isdigit(r) != 0;

                 return (!ldigit && rdigit) || (ldigit == rdigit && l < r);
            });
    }
};
```

And use it...

```
std::map<string, list<pair<string, int>>, custom_comparer> List;
```

Normal `string` comparison operators use [`lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare). My `custom_comparer` above also uses it, but with a custom comparer plugged in. The custom comparer uses [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) to do the comparison you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your own comparer:

```
struct custom_string_comparer
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
    {
         return ...; // your comparison here
    }
};

map<string, list<pair<string, int>>, custom_string_comparer> List;
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes. You need to supply a third template argument, see the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Comment: Although your statement is correct, it is not helpful on its own. At least write down a minimal example just like the others. Also, cplusplus.com is not _the docs_.